# How to automatically create a table on a predefined interval (e.g. month) using current_date()

Tags: postgresql, presto

I would like to automatically create a table, in my postgresql db, every month using stored data. Every time the query runs I would like the table name to change dynamically (e.g table_JAN2018, table_FEB2018, table_MAR2018 etc) so as a new table is created with the new data of that month while the old tables remain intact.

After researching, I found that I can achieve this (?) as described in the link below: [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter)

So I tried, in same fashion, the code below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION table_Jan2018() RETURNS void as 
$func$
BEGIN 
EXECUTE

'create table' || to_char(current_date, '%b/%Y'|| 'as select * from
(
select
id,product, client, purchase_date, sales_status,
case when complete_transaction_date is null then cast(purchase_date as date)
when verified  is not null  then cast(complete_transaction_date  as date)
end as purchase
from clients
where sales_status in ('state1','state2')
and test=false
)
where purchase>=(current_date - interval '30' day)';
end;
```

However, what i get is the following error message in presto:
"no viable alternative at input 'CREATE FUNCTION' "

Is the above function suitable in order to change dynamically the table name as I need? Is there another way to achieve what i want?

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where is your actual code?

Comment: use dynamic sql. whats the question btw?..

Comment: Thank you guys for your interest! I have updated my post with the code i tried to run! @derHugo

Comment: please run it wotj psql or pgadmin, not presto